# Find multiple item in json with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have json look like this:

```
{
"data": [{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "city": "Paris"
}, {
    "first_name": "Ali",
    "last_name": null,
    "city": "Tehran"
}, {
    "first_name": "mohsen",
    "last_name": "dou",
    "city": "Tehran"
}, {
    "first_name": "mohsen",
    "last_name": "yoou",
    "city": "Istanbul"
}}]
}
```

I want to find this criteria:

```
{
"first_name": "mohsen",
"city": "Tehran"
}
```

from first json 
expected result:

```
{
"first_name": "mohsen",
"last_name": "dou",
"city": "Tehran"
}
```

> consider find two or more criteria from json.

Comment: Quera contest? There wouldn't be anything more than iterating over `data` objects and checking for given values. All at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you can use array_intersect_key to get selected keys

```
$arr = json_decode($arr_json, True);
$criteria = json_decode($criteria_json, True);

$found = array_filter($arr['data'], 
    function($x) use($criteria) { 
        return $criteria == array_intersect_key($x, $criteria) ;
    });
```